# How can the User Interface know which commands is allowed to perform against an Aggregate Root?

Tags: user-interface, domain-driven-design, cqrs

The UI is decoupled from the domain, but the UI should try its best to never allow the user to issue commands that are sure to fail.
Consider the following example (pseudo-code):

```
DiscussionController
    @Security(is_logged)
    @Method('POST')
    @Route('addPost')
    addPostToDiscussionAction(request)
        discussionService.postToDiscussion(
            new PostToDiscussionCommand(request.discussionId, session.myUserId, request.bodyText)
        )

    @Method('GET')
    @Route('showDiscussion/{discussionId}')
    showDiscussionAction(request)
        discussionWithAllThePosts = discussionFinder.findById(request.discussionId)

        canAddPostToThisDiscussion = ???

        // render the discussion to the user, and use `canAddPostToThisDiscussion` to show/hide the form
        // from which the user can send a request to `addPostToDiscussionAction`.
        renderDiscussion(discussionWithAllThePosts, canAddPostToThisDiscussion)

PostToDiscussionCommand
    constructor(discussionId, authorId, bodyText)

DiscussionApplicationService
    postToDiscussion(command)
        discussion = discussionRepository.get(command.discussionId)
        author = collaboratorService.authorFrom(discussion.Id, command.authorId)
        post = discussion.createPost(postRepository.nextIdentity(), author, command.bodyText)
        postRepository.add(post)

DiscussionAggregate
    // originalPoster is the Author that started the discussion
    constructor(discussionId, originalPoster)

    // if the discussion is closed, you can't create a post.
    // *unless* if you're the author (OP) that started the discussion 
    createPost(postId, author, bodyText)
        if (this.close && !this.originalPoster.equals(author))
            throw "Discussion is closed."

        return new Post(this.discussionId, postId, author, bodyText)

    close()
        if (this.close)
            throw "Discussion already closed."

        this.close = true

    isClosed()
        return this.close
```

- The user goes to `/showDiscussion/123` and he see the discussion with the `<form>` from which he can submit a new post, but only if the discussion is not closed or the current user is who started that discussion.
- Or, the user goes to `/showDiscussion/123` where it's presented as a REST-as-in-HATEOAS API. A hypermedia link to `/addPost` will be provided, only if the discussion is not closed or the authenticated user is who started that discussion.

**How can I provide that knowledge into the UI?**

I could code that into the read model,

```
canAddPostToThisDiscussion = !discussionWithAllThePosts.discussion.isClosed
    && discussionWithAllThePosts.discussion.originalPoster.id == session.currentUserId
```

but then I need to maintain that logic and keep it in sync with the write model. This is a fairly simple example, but as the states transitions of an aggregate become more complex, it may become really hard to do. I'd like to image my aggregates as state machines, with their workflows (like the [RESTBucks](https://vimeo.com/41763224) example). But I don't like the idea to move that business logic outside my domain model, and put it in a service that both the read side and write side can use.

Maybe this isn't the best example, but as an aggregate root is basically a consistency boundary, we know that we need to prevent invalid state transitions in its life cycle, and in each transitions to a new state some operations may become illegal and vice versa. So, how can the user interface know what is allowed or not? What are my alternative? How should I approach to this problem? Do you have any example to provide?

Comment: The response you are looking for is HATEOAS

Answer (score 2):

> How can I provide that knowledge into the UI?

The easiest way is probably to share the domain model's understanding of what is possible with the UI.  Ta Da.

Here's a way to think about it -- in the abstract, all of the write model logic has a fairly simple looking shape.

```
{
    // Notice that these statements are queries
    State currentState = bookOfRecord.getState()
    State nextState = model.computeNextState(currentState, command)

    // This statement is a command
    bookOfRecord.replace(currentState, nextState)
}
```

Key ideas here: the book of record is the authority of *state*; everybody else (including the "write model") is working with a stale copy.

What the model represents is a collection of constraints that ensure that the business invariant is satisfied.  Over the lifetime of a system, there might be many different sets of constraints, as the understanding of the business changes.

The write model is the authority for which collection of constraints is currently enforced when replacing the state in the book of record.  Everybody else is working with a stale copy.

The staleness is something to keep in mind; in a distributed system, any validation you perform is provisional -- unless you have a lock on the state and a lock on the model, either could be changed while your messages are in flight.

This means that your validation is approximate anyway, so you don't need to be too concerned that you have all of the fiddly details right.  You assume that your stale copy of the state is approximately right, and your current understanding of the model is approximately right, and if the command is valid given those pre-conditions, then it is checked enough to send.

> I don't like the idea to move that business logic outside my domain model, and put it in a service that both the read side and write side can use.

I think the best answer here is "get over it".  I get it; because having the business logic inside the aggregate root is what the literature is telling us to do.  But if you continue to refactor, identifying common patterns and separating concerns, you'll see that entities are really just plumbing around a reference to state and a [functional core](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/functional-core-imperative-shell).

```
AggregateRoot {
    final Reference<State> bookOfRecord;
    final Model<State,Command> theModel;

    onCommand(Command command) {
        State currentState = bookOfRecord.getState()
        State nextState = model.computeNextState(currentState, command)

        bookOfRecord.replace(currentState, nextState)
    }            
}
```

All we've done here is taken the "construct the next state" logic, which we used to have scattered through out the AggregateRoot, and encapsulated it into a separate responsibility boundary.  Here, its specific to the root itself, but an equivalent refactoring it so pass it as an argument.

```
AggregateRoot {
    final Reference<State> bookOfRecord;

    onCommand(Model<State,Command> theModel, Command command) {
        State currentState = bookOfRecord.getState()
        State nextState = model.computeNextState(currentState, command)

        bookOfRecord.replace(currentState, nextState)
    }            
}
```

In other words, the model, teased out from the plumbing of tracking state, is a *domain service*.  The domain logic within the domain service is just as much a part of the domain model as the domain logic within the aggregate -- the two implementations are dual to one another.

And there's no reason that a read model of your domain shouldn't have access to a domain service.

Comment: They key problematic here seems to be the tensions between authorization logic and business logic. "only OP can post on closed dicussions". If that was evolving to something more complex such as "only moderators and OP...etc". I'm not entirely sure what is the best approach to cope with that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the idea of sharing domain knowlegde (code) between the write and the read models as you will have to continously keep them in sync and that'd really a chalenge even if you are the only developer in your company.

But the good knews is that you don't have to duplicate anything. If you designed your `Aggregate` to be pure, with no side effect as you should do (!), you can simply send it the command but without persisting the changes. If the command throws an exception then the command would not succeed, otherwise the command would succeed. In case of CQRS this is even better as you have a 3rd outcome: idempotent command detection in which case the command succeeds but it has no effect (no events are raised but no exception is thrown either) and the UI might find this interesting.

So, as an example you could have something like this:

```
DiscussionController
    @Security(is_logged)
    @Method('POST')
    @Route('addPost')
    addPostToDiscussionAction(request)
        discussionService.postToDiscussion(
            new PostToDiscussionCommand(request.discussionId, session.myUserId, request.bodyText)
        )

    @Method('GET')
    @Route('showDiscussion/{discussionId}')
    showDiscussionAction(request)
        discussionWithAllThePosts = discussionFinder.findById(request.discussionId)

     canAddPostToThisDiscussion = discussionService.canPostToDiscussion(request.discussionId, session.myUserId, "some sample body")

        // render the discussion to the user, and use `canAddPostToThisDiscussion` to show/hide the form
        // from which the user can send a request to `addPostToDiscussionAction`.
        renderDiscussion(discussionWithAllThePosts, canAddPostToThisDiscussion)

DiscussionApplicationService
    postToDiscussion(command)
        discussion = discussionRepository.get(command.discussionId)
        author = collaboratorService.authorFrom(discussion.Id, command.authorId)
        post = discussion.createPost(postRepository.nextIdentity(), author, command.bodyText)
        postRepository.add(post)

    canPostToDiscussion(discussionId, authorId, bodyText)
        discussion = discussionRepository.get(discussionId)
        author = collaboratorService.authorFrom(discussion.Id, authorId)
        try
        {
                post = discussion.createPost(postRepository.nextIdentity(), author, bodyText)
                return true
        }
        catch (exception)
        {
                return false
         }
```

You could even have a method named `whyCantPostToDiscussion` that would return the exception or the exception message and display it in the UI.

There is only one issue with the code: the call to `postRepository.nextIdentity()` because it would increase the next ID every time but you could replace it with something like `postRepository.getBiggestIdentity()` that should have no side effect.

Comment: I can't say that I like the idea to send a command on the read side just to check if sending that command could throw an exception. Loading the aggregate and retrieve the author (potentially from another BC) each time on the read side would be expensive at least.

Comment: @Federkun I use it with success on a event-sourced aggregate repository with 1,000,000 aggregates and I can tell you that is fast as no locking is necessary. No writing is performed. Aggregate's encapsulation is protected and the Aggregate's authority is straightened. No knowlege duplication, no service is stealing power from Aggregate. Aggregate is not in risk of becoming anemic. And is explicit: "would command succeed in current system state?".

Comment: @Federkun also, in case of high availability and hi scalability (at the cost of eventual consistency) you can replicate the Aggregate repository along the read side.

Comment: What could be slow and exploited though is throwing exceptions. It that approach is used quite commonly then perhaps you should return a command result from aggregate operations rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: @plalx exceptions are just fine,  I like them but whatever style works too as long as it is explicit.

Comment: I wrote an article about this here https://github.com/xprt64/cqrs-es/blob/master/docs/QueryingAnAggregate.md

Comment: I agree that it's an interesting approach. I've used it to solve similar problems (e.g. try to parse to validate the format of some string), but I just wanted to say that generating exceptions is much more costly because of the stack trace filling (should be similar in most languages). Will it be noticeable, I don't know? By the way you may want to correct this sentence `"neither of these methods **do not conform** to the DDD rules"`. I think you did not meant "do not"?

Comment: I agree, it's an interesting approach that someone could consider, that could works fine under some cases, and not in others (example: if the commands are sent asynchronously). I still think that the advantages don't overcome the disadvantages, but it's good to have this option when it could.

Comment: @Federkun one could combine this idea with a read model: construct a readmodel that contains a prop for each needed command with a boolean as value indicating the success of a future command.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU, that will be problematic if the logic depends on the calling user (as it does here). You potentially need n*m rows in the read model - one for each user for each entity. Any more efficient approach can't really use 'check the command' and is going to have to be more wired into the business logic. Your approach couples the read side to the write side. The alternative is to couple both the read side and the write side to the common logic/service.

Comment: @TomW indeed, however, in many cases of mine user dependant verifications are done in another bounded context so in an eventually consistent maner. This can be implemented as an **aditional** command validators layer. I hope I make sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

I find it is rare that authorization is actually part of the domain. If it isn't, it makes sense to move that logic out into its own service which the UI and the domain can make use of.

I like to build up a set of rules using the specification pattern. I find it to be a fairly elegant way to build up the rules.

This also plays very well in a CQRS context as you can run each command through the 'rules engine' before they get issued to your AR's. If you push queries through a message routeing system you can do the same for queries. I've had a lot of success with this approach.

Comment: Do you consider the `if forum closed` part of authorization as well? That's the piece I'm not sure of. Would you have `postToDiscussion //check if closed` and `forcePostToDiscussion //no policy enforcement` where the authorization to call `postToDiscussion` or `forcePostToDiscussion` is enforced at the application layer level? When rules become more complex (e.g. officer can approve loan below 10000, but manager is required to approve loan above 10000)... is that authorization or business rules?

Comment: Yes is the short answer. I built a not untrivial rules engine around user permissions, document states, document versions and publishing rules. I used that approach and it worked fairly well. I did end up with surprisingly simple AR's but that's part of the point. They ended up being very focused and therefore very simple.

Comment: So, the invariant in my example aren't really invariant that belong to the AR? Fairly enough, but how would you deal with the example provided by Evans about the Purchase Order that has a "maximum allowable total" assigned, and the sum of all the purchase order's Line Items must not surpass the allowable total? (I'm not interested in how to solve this with eventual consistency, saga, etc, I was just looking for a true consistency rule that live in the AR). Should I enforce that rule in the application layer as well? And if I should, how could my AR not suffer from anemia?

Comment: Good question - You've got to draw a line somewhere. It sounds like you want to full model on the front end. At some point, the user will ask to do something which they can't. And that's ok. Just through an exception and handle gracefully on the UI. I suggest not trying to cover all bases on the front end like that.

Comment: Well, suddenly then all business logic becomes authorization logic, because at the end of the day you can always override rules in most scenarios. True invariants almost doesn't exist e.g. even if there's a policy in place, you almost always have a possible override (e.g. spoke to a manager over the phone). That means your aggregates will almost contain no logic at all while all your logic is externalized in a infrastructure-focused rule-engine implementation. The exact opposite of what DDD advocates...

Comment: For instance, you could have built a system that packs products into containers based on several rules, but there's most likely a workflow in there that allows someone to take responsibility and stamp "put that toxic product in that non-standard container anyway". In my mind that would yield a different workflow (`autoPack` and `manuallyPackProduct`) where only some kind of "high level employee" could call the manual workflow.

Comment: If we make a parallel between example, I'd say you could have a standard `postToDiscussion` workflow that prevents anyone from posting to closed discussions and a secondary workflow `forcePostToDiscussion` that can be called by OP and admin only for instance. That keeps the `if closed` rule in the domain in a standard workflow while explicitly showing that there's an alternate workflow that ignores the posting policy. Still, that makes the calling code slightly more complex then because you have to figure out which workflow you must call, unless perhaps that is done in the command handler.

Comment: This has the added benefit of making the implicit explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The response you are looking for is HATEOAS, look no further. You must implement your rest api as really restful (level 3) adhering to hypertext to model the state transitions and return links to the clients (being the UI one of those). These links represent the actions the user can execute in its context according to the model state. It´s simple. If you return a link from the server then you bind it to a button in the UI, if you don´t return the link because of business invariants then you do not show the button on the UI. There is a lot more of concepts behind it such as designing a good API supporting a well designed domain model behind but this is the general idea around it and fits exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure you've understood my question.

Comment: I did, this is exactly what you need but you need to grasp a whole new subject and might involve a deep learning curve to get the rounded idea.

Comment: The question is **how** the server knows when to put the links in the response and when not to put them.